# atlwin and modern c++ - specifically Create taking a RECT by value

Tags: c++, winapi, c++20, wtl

Porting an existing WTL application to C++20. One of the issues we're running into is that atlwin.h has a method "Create" with the following signature:

```
    HWND Create(
    _In_opt_ HWND hWndParent,
    _In_ _U_RECT rect = NULL,
    _In_opt_z_ LPCTSTR szWindowName = NULL,
    _In_ DWORD dwStyle = 0,
    _In_ DWORD dwExStyle = 0,
    _In_ _U_MENUorID MenuOrID = 0U,
    _In_opt_ LPVOID lpCreateParam = NULL)
```

and was being called like this:

```
Create(hWnd, CRECT(0,0, 100, 200), ....)
```

The constructor for _U_RECT only takes a reference to a RECT or a pointer to a RECT, which means that you cannot pass a temporary in.

How have people worked around this? I'd hate to have to go through all of the code and replace the above code with:

```
CRect tmpRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
Create(hwnd, tmpRect, .....);
```

The version of MSVC being used is 14.37.32822.

Comment: That has actually been an issue before as well, it's not something new in the C++20 standard. The problem is that older versions of MSVC did allow non-constant references bind to temporary values, as a non-standard and non-portable extension of the C++ language. It seems it has been removed, or that it needs some other extra flag to be enabled (which I recommend you don't do). And unfortunately, if you want to be standards-compliant then there's really no other solution than using a temporary variable.

Comment: As a possible *workaround* you could create an overload that takes the argument by value, and then calls the real function and passing the argument variable. It's essentially the same solution as using a temporary variable, but in a nicer way.

Comment: I'm confused. C++20 is supported starting with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11, but you seem to be using VS 2015. Is that information accurate?

Comment: @IInspectable - What makes you think we’re using VS 2015? We are on VS 2022.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Do you know if there are newer versions of MSVC which have more modern interfaces? The issue here is _U_RECT, which appears to be a support class that allows you to pass either a pointer to a RECT, or a RECT as a parameter, but does not allow the use of a temporary RECT.

Comment: *"The version of MSVC being used is 14.37.32822."* - v14 is VS 2015.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with MSVC itself, it's the Windows API that is designed this way.

Comment: The compiler version is meaningful in devising a solution/temporary workaround. Since `/std:c++20` implies [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance), passing `/permissive` can serve as a way to get unblocked. But that requires 16.8.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Isnt atlwin.h part of MSVC? In which case they could have updated _U_RECT so that it could also be constructed with a temporary.

Comment: @IInspectable - I’m using VS 2022, but 14.xxx is the highest version that is listed in the project settings. Does a newer version of MSVC not get installed with VS 2022?

Answer (score 0):

I went with a mixin class to add a new method, which I was able to use in all the places I derived from WinImpl.

It added a Create method which had a CRect by value.